# IntelliJ IDEA freezes on Startup | Plugin Development

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for IntelliJ, in 95% of the cases the second IntelliJ window starts and then freezes without opening the IDE.
[image] 
Run Console and idea.log are both empty.
Please tell me if you need further information.

### **Edit:**

I run my plugin with this config:
[image: run]

I also created a gradle project for the plugin, this does not work neither.
[image: gradle run]

Comment: How do you run your plugin? Perhaps you have a brake point at startup?

Comment: @Feedforward please check out my edit

Comment: check threaddump

Comment: @Meo I can't because it's greyed out